# MySQL: How to Count total orders by hour from a specific date range

Tags: sql, database

Customer_placed_order_datetime

01 00:00:20

02 01:00:00

31 23:59:00

I want to count the total number of orders that has been made every hour from 01 - 31 days

example outcome:

```
                  01-31 HOUR         total_orders

                  1st hour                500
                  2nd hour                400
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Good. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Many RDBMS have functions to format dates and cast to string.
For example, with PostgreSQL, you can use `TO_CHAR(date_value, string_format)`. With this new format date (ask only the yyyyMMdd), you can group and count your orders.
If you tag your RDBMS, I can help you more precisely

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out and helping. Im using Big Query  MySql google cloud, basically Im making a case study to find out correlation of orders and time per hour for like a food app. I want to count the total customer_placed_order by hour from a day 1 to 31. thank you

Comment: Normally this should work: 
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d') as day, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%H') as hour, COUNT(*) as total_orders FROM Customer_placed_order_datetime GROUP BY datetime`

Comment: Function not found: DATE_FORMAT at [1:8]                                                            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d') as day, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%H') as hour, COUNT(*) as total_orders 
FROM `deductive-span-328102.FoodDelivery.FD123` 
GROUP BY datetime

Comment: The database name is : `deductive-span-328102.FoodDelivery.FD123`   and column name  :  Customer_placed_order_datetime

Comment: See this documentation for Google Big Query : [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract). Replace DATE_FORMAT with the EXTRACT function

`SELECT EXTRACT(DAY, datetime) as day, EXTRACT(HOUR, datetime) as hour, COUNT(*) as total_orders FROM Customer_placed_order_datetime GROUP BY datetime`